# Using redshift as a JDBC source for readStream in the Structured Streaming API (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, spark-structured-streaming

Im looking for a package, or a previous implementation of using redshift as the source for a structured streaming dataframe.

```
spark.readStream \
    .format("io.github.spark_redshift_community.spark.redshift") \
    .option('url', redshift_url) \
    .option('forward_spark_s3_credentials', 'true') \
    .load()
```

Using the format below you get errors on the read. such as:

```
Data source io.github.spark_redshift_community.spark.redshift does not support streamed reading
```

This is the same error if you downgrade from Spark 3 and use: `com.databricks.spark.redshift`

Is there a known workaround, or methodology/pattern i can use to implement (in pyspark) redshift as a readStream datasource

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, this library does not support streaming reads/ writes to/ from Redshift.

Same can be confirmed from the project source [at link](https://github.com/spark-redshift-community/spark-redshift/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/github/spark_redshift_community/spark/redshift/DefaultSource.scala). The format does not extend or implement Micro/ Continuous stream readers and writers.

There will be no `true streaming` easy ways to this. You may explore the following avenues,

1. Explore 3rd party libs. Search for `JDBC streaming spark`. Disclaimer: I have not used these and thus do not endorse these libs.
2. Create a Micro-batching strategy on a custom check-pointing mechanism.

**Extended Note:** AFAIK, Spark JDBC interfaces do not support Structured Streaming.